# Which verison of Opessl uses PEM_read_RSA_PUBKEY?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, openssl

I want to compile a cpp project in Ubuntu that uses openSSL and it's function PEM_read_RSA_PUBKEY.

Although i can't find an older version using that function and when i compile the program with the newest openSSL version it returns an error saying

```
undefined reference 'PEM_read_RSA_PUBKEY'
```

How can i solve this error??

Comment: Did you #include <openssl/pem.h>?

Comment: yes, also if I edit the pem.h of the latest openSSL, I can't see any function like this one...Although I see it mentioned in other sites too..

Comment: It looks like `PEM_read_RSA_PUBKEY` is declared and defined at ln:198, pem_all.c.

Comment: just checked this!!you are right..but how can i use this from pem.h??

Comment: How do you compile your program? Can you paste the relevant code of your program using PEM_read_RSA_PUBKEY? Give us more information.

Comment: `FILE *pemfile = fopen("myserverpubkey2.pem",  "rb");  fopen("myserver.pem", "rb");  
RSA *rsa_pub = PEM_read_RSA_PUBKEY(pemfile, NULL, NULL, NULL);  
(FILE *fp, NULL, NULL, NULL);  
 fclose(pemfile);`


this is the code i want to compile..I compile it with the make command, it's an open source project (a sip client called twinkle) that three years ago a friend of mine added some encryption.

Comment: I compiled your program with `gcc main.c -o main -lcrypto -lssl`, it will pass without undefined reference. My guess is that you can get a devel version OpenSSL, or you can look at the twinkle Makefile to see if it links the libraries correctly. Good luck.